# Add records in Microsoft Access form without showing/editing other records

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in Microsoft Access where I want users to be able to add records to a table, but I don't want existing records to be visible in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Set the *Data Entry* property of the form to *Yes*